# How can I set the index of a generated pandas Series to a column from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

In pandas this operation creates a Series:

`q7.loc[:, list(q7)].max(axis=1) - q7.loc[:, list(q7)].min(axis=1)`

I would like to be able to set the index as a list of values from a df colum. Ie

```
list(df['Colname'])
```

I've tried to create the series then update it with the series generated from the first code snippet. I've also searched the docs and don't see a method that will allow me to do this. I would prefer not to manually iterate over it.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `(q7.loc[:, list(q7)].max(axis=1) - q7.loc[:, list(q7)].min(axis=1)).set_index(df['Colname'])` assuming their shapes are compatible.

Comment: The shapes for the series and the df column are the same as well: (3142,)
(3142,)

Comment: You want to reindex or add additional index(create multiindex)?

Comment: Alright setting the series as a new column in the dataframe was much easier. Although if anyone figures the original question out that would be cool to know.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `set_index` won't be available for pandas Series if I remember correctly.!! Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @SreeramTP Yup, forgot about that. You would need to assign the index manually as you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store that series to a variable say `S` and set the index accordingly as shown below..!!

```
S = (q7.loc[:, list(q7)].max(axis=1) - q7.loc[:, list(q7)].min(axis=1))

S.index = df['Colname']
```

The code is provided assuming the lengths of the series and Column from the dataframe is equal. Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset series `s` index, you can do:

```
s.index = new_index_list
```

Comment: ah, that's it. Thank you